# Disable parallel build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to ask how can I disable the parallel build for Visual Studio 2019 C# projects?

Answer (score 9):

You can effectively 'disable' building multiple projects in parallel by setting the maximum to 1.

Select the "Options" command from the "Tools" menu and then, in the shown pop-up dialogue box, open the "Projects and Solutions" node in the left-hand pane and select the "Build and Run" sub-node.

In the right-hand pane, enter "1" in the edit box (at the top) labelled, "maximum number of parallel project builds".

[image]